# Como Selecionar item do ListView em Java

Tags: java, android

Como usar o método para trabalhar com o item selecionado da ListView?

Activity:

```
public class ListaProntos extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
ContactImageAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
/**
* CRUD Operations
* */
// Inserting Contacts
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts("Pronto");
for (Contact cn : contacts) {

//add contacts data in arrayList
imageArry.add(cn);

}
adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,imageArry); 
ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
dataList.setAdapter(adapter);

dataList.setOnItemClickListener(this); // Clique no item
}


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Código para trabalhar com o item que foi clicado
    // position é a posição do item no adapter

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position of Selected Item is :-"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.55" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

scree_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/cinza_claro"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textBancada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Orden de Serviço: "
            android:textColor="@color/azul_escuro"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="os"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cliente:  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCliente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Cliente"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescricao"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Descrição"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" 

         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDatahor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data hora"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:onClick="menuAcao" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Situação:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
                android:textColor="@color/azul_escuro"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Localização: "
                android:textColor="@color/azul_escuro"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLocal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="local"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="id"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: o que você quer fazer exatamente no seu método de click do item de um `ListView`?  Você por acaso quer recuperar o seu objeto `Contact` do Adapter? Até o presente momento está com algum erro?

Comment: você está criando muitas perguntas no SO Português e deixando para trás, sem dar retorno se conseguiu ou não. Se largou de mão ou não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve registrar um `OnItemClickListener` ou um `OnItemLongClickListener` na seu `ListView`, quando um item for selecionado (`ItemClick`) ou pressionado (`ItemLongClick`) você será notificado.

Para escutar por esses eventos você deve fazer algo como:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        dataList.setOnItemClickListener(this); // Clique no item
        dataList.setOnItemLongClickListener(this); // Pressão sobre o item

        // Mais codigo...
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Código para trabalhar com o item que foi clicado
        // position é a posição do item no adapter
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Código para trabalhar com o item que foi pressionado
        // position é a posição do item no adapter
    }
}
```

Além disso recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) e do [`AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html).

Tenho uma sugestão para que o código funcione, remova qualquer `View` que gere ação ou foco (Button, ImageButton, EditText, etc...) do layout do seu item.

Para que a seleção funcione com esses elementos, você precisa adaptar o layout do seu `ListView`. Para isso sugiro a leitura do seguinte artigo: [Several Clickable Areas in ListView](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/) e [MultiTouch ListView](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html).

Elas exigiram uma grande alteração no layout e a criação de uma `View` customizada para melhor efeito.

Comment: Wakim! dá uma olhada nesses erros: `dataList.setOnItemClickListener(this); //The method  setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (ListaProntos) dataList.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);//The method setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (ListaProntos)`

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos, não falta colocar `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` na sua classe `ListProntos`?

Comment: Faltava mesmo! mas é incrível como nada acontece ao clicar na lista. o deve ser?

Comment: Poderia atualizar o código incluindo o layout do item inflado no adapter?

Comment: Ok, atualizado!